# How do I specify a Primary Key in an INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: null, ssms, insert-into

I have looked at others but not finding out how to solve this in the framework of the following query. The others on here are vastly more complex. I get the error message below. I am trying to essentially copy the wage column from dbo.something and place it in dbo.sizeclassreportgov.

I do not want to auto increment. In this case, the PK is State which always has a value of 32. How would I specify a PK value of 32 in the framework of the below query?

```
Insert into dbo.sizeclassreportgov(wage)
select wage from dbo.something;

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 617
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'state', table 
'wid27.dbo.sizeclassreportgov'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sizeclassreportgov(wage)  
SELECT 32 FROM dbo.something
```

Note this will insert the value, 32, for each row in *dbo.something*.

Comment: The query is designed to get my wage data from dbo.something to dbo.sizeclassreportgov. Would this impose a value of 32 on every instance of wage?

Comment: I tried your query and I get the same error message as in the original question

Comment: Yes, it does. I have done Inserts on this table just an hour ago and they worked.

Comment: Ok, so when you issue the _INSERT_ statement in your original post and you are receiving a "Cannot insert a value NULL into column" message, it means that a NULL value exists in the **dbo.something.wage** column for one or more rows.  You need to find those rows (`SELECT Wage FROM dbo.Something WHERE Wage IS NULL`) and fix them.

Comment: OK, I will go down that road.